Stripe Payment in Next.js: Webhook Issue - 401 (Unauthorized)
I am attempting to integrate Stripe (subscription) checkouts into my Next.js app (14 w/ app router).
TL;DR:
I think this may be an issue with Next.js because when I execute a curl command to my applications /api/webhooks/stripe I get a 401 just like shows in my Stripe dev dashboard logs. Seems to indicate that the Next server is requiring authentication for this api route. I don't have a middleware.ts or anything like that so I don't know what would be causing this.
I followed this repo & this video
Everything works locally. I sign in, scribe by completing a (test) payment through the Stripe form/page I get redirected to, I am redirected back to my app and then I see that in my data base my user record has been updated (with the stripe_customer_id for example).
Then I set up a webhook and point it staging deployment on vercel https://subdomain.domain.xyz/api/webhooks/stripe. I am able to complete the Stripe payment and I get redirected back to my application page from the Stripe form / page. But the user record in the database doesn't get updated with any of the stripe info and I see error's in the stripe webhook logs:
HTTP status code
401 (Unauthorized)
<!doctype html><html lang=en><meta charset=utf-8><meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><title>Authentication Required</title>...

I don't have any middleware.ts on my Next.js app or anything like that.
My STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET is properly set to the value shown in the Stripe Dev Dashboard for the webhook.
I don't see and of the console.log's inside my src/app/api/webhooks/stripe/route.ts in my vercel deployment logs (but I do see these logs when I do this locally). It seems to me that the request to the webhook url I've set is being rejected before the the handler even gets a chance to handle the POST request.
I'm using server actions, which at the time the tutorial was made were experimental, but I'm on Next 14+ so they should be fully supported.
Does anyone recognize this error or know how I might resolve this?

Do the other endpoints on your server require authentication? If it is working locally for you, but not on your vercel deploy, it is possible that vercel can help you look in to why your endpoint is requiring authentication here

I've seen a few similar issues posted on this so I'll add that, in my case:
I was pushing to a staging branch and in MyProject > Settings > Deployment Protection:
Vercel Authentication was enabled and I needed to disable it.
I would have liked to keep it enabled and just whitelist Stripe. If anyone knows how to do that please comment. thx.
